# Replace a value in NSDictionary in iPhone

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary

I have a array (dataArray) of NSDictionary "item". It has datas like "david" for key "name" and "85" for key "marks" etc for 5 students. I want to replace the mark of david to 90 with respect to the array index value (ie 0 for dictionary containing david and 85). How can I do it?

The code for content in array is

```
[item setobject:name forkey:@"Name"];
[item setobject:mark forkey:@"Marks"];
[dataArray addOject:item]
```

The above code goes inside parsing, so i have array with 5 objects (students), their name and marks, now I want to replace the mark of the first object in the dataArray.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Here's what you can do:

```
NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSDictionary *oldDict = (NSDictionary *)[dataArray objectAtIndex:0];
[newDict addEntriesFromDictionary:oldDict];
[newDict setObject:@"Don" forKey:@"Name"];
[dataArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:newDict];
[newDict release];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: changed objectForIndex to objectAtIndex.Thanks

Answer (score 30):

You first need an NSMutableDictionary with it you can change the key and value.

It would be like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"david", @"name", "85", @"marks", nil];

[dict setObject:@"90" forKey:@"david"];
```

Comment: I gave David as example, i am getting these values after parsing, so how can give that value as static?

Comment: This is simple and better answer

Answer (score 12):

```
 // NSDictionary *dict = ...
    NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [dict mutableCopy];
    [mutableDict setObject:@"myObject" forKey:@"myKey"];
    dict = [mutableDict mutableCopy];
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 10):

If you want to update an object in a NSDictionary you should use **NSMutableDictionary** instead.
NSMutableDictionary has the following EXTRA methods

Adding Entries

- setObject:forKey:
- setValue:forKey:
- addEntriesFromDictionary:
- setDictionary:

Removing Entries

- removeObjectForKey:
- removeAllObjects
- removeObjectsForKeys:

Answer (score 1):

```
[davidsRecord setObject:@"100" forkey:@"mark"];
```